# ansible become_exe: "sudo su -" adds more paramters (-H -S -n -u user)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ansible

I have passwordless connection to specific servers. On this server my user can do "sudo su - user"

```
> $ ssh host

myuser@host:~ $ sudo su - new_user
new_user@host:~ $
```

I want to achieve this same with Ansible playbook.

```
---

- hosts: my_group
  remote_user: myuser
  tasks:
          - name: "whoami"
            become: yes
            become_exe: "sudo su -"
            become_method: sudo
            become_user: "new_user"
            command: whoami
            register: result
          - debug: msg="{{ result.stdout }}"
```

**When I run playbook:**

```
> user / ansib $ ansible-playbook int.yaml

PLAY [int] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host]

TASK [who am i] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
host                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Debug:**

```
TASK [who am i] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /login/myuser/ansib/cert.yaml:10
<host> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser
<host> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/login/myuser/.ansible/cp/0dd1c5b064 host '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~myuser && sleep 0'"'"''
<host> (0, '/home/myuser\n', '')
<host> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser
<host> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/login/myuser/.ansible/cp/0dd1c5b064 host '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /var/tmp `"&& mkdir /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022 && echo ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022="` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<host> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022=/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022\n', '')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
<host> PUT /login/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-31097VQMw2J/tmpwKIGsv TO /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022/AnsiballZ_command.py
<host> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/login/myuser/.ansible/cp/0dd1c5b064 '[host]'
<host> (0, 'sftp> put /login/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-31097VQMw2J/tmpwKIGsv /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', '')
<host> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser
<host> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/login/myuser/.ansible/cp/0dd1c5b064 host '/bin/sh -c '"'"'setfacl -m u:new_user:r-x /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<host> (0, '', '')
<host> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser
<host> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/login/myuser/.ansible/cp/0dd1c5b064 -tt host '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo su - -H -S -n  -u new_user /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-udwnqqirghwxmfmdebilbiitxqeurmzg ; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<host> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: myuser
<host> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="myuser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/login/myuser/.ansible/cp/0dd1c5b064 host '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1588766128.54-31125-82317805935022/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<host> (0, '', '')
```

This line:

```
sudo su - -H -S -n  -u new_user /bin/sh -c
```

And of course if I run this command by my own I do also have password prompt.

I have also tried to move some things around and I've changed my playbook and I've added also become_flags parameter:

```
---

- hosts: my_group
  remote_user: myuser
  tasks:
          - name: "whoami"
            become: yes
            become_exe: "sudo su -"
            become_method: sudo
            become_user: "new_user"
            become_flags: ""
            command: whoami
            register: result
          - debug: msg="{{ result.stdout }}"
```

and it's a bit better...

```
sudo su -  new_user -c
```

Unfortunately adding "-c" keeps asking me for password...

Any idea if I can somehow become as new_user without "-c" parameter, or run command as new_user?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can `sudo` as `my_user` to `new_user` without password on the command line, this playbook should be able to do the trick:

```
- hosts: my_group
  remote_user: my_user

  tasks:

  - command: whoami
    become: yes
    become_user: new_user
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result.stdout
```

No need to specify `become_method` or `become_exe` if you'll be using anyway the defaults.